# Preventing collider from glitching through terrain

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, game-development

I'm using a terrain in `Unity 2019.2.1f1` and a custom mesh of a cave with a mesh collider.

My character that has a Capsule Collider way bigger than the entry of the cave should not be able to enter in. But due to the roundness of both colliders, he can come into force in the cave, **glitching through the terrain** collider.

I think it's velocity is not excessive, I'm moving the character with `rb.MovePosition()` in the `FixedUpdate()`, and I set its rigidbody collision detection to **Continuous speculative** (*tried all the "continuous" modes*)

In the animation below, you can see the mesh of the cave and the capsule collider around the character.

How can I prevent this from happening? How can I say to Unity: "I want the colliders to be rock solid and not marshmallow"?

[image: collider_glitch]

Comment: Try using `rb.AddForce` instead of `rb.MovePosition`

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to use `MovePosition` but since this problem, I think I will use a mix of `AddForce` and RootMotion (thanks to the `OnAnimatorMove()` callback).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colliders in Unity *are* rock-solid. They are incapable of any kind of soft physics, and the only moment they will warp through each other is when you force them to.

Here, you are setting the rigidBody position by force, into an impossible location. The game tries its best to fit your rigidBody despite the lack of room.

You can

- Only use forces, and velocities. You can simply set the velocity to the direction of your choosing, and set it to 0 when you stop moving, or use `AddForce`, which is basically the same thing.
- Keep using `MovePosition`, but use a `SphereCast` or `CapsuleCast` to check if you have enough room to move first.

Comment: Ok thank you for the explanation, I thought of doing well using `MovePosition()` and not directly changing the position of the player. Because the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) says "it  creates a smooth transition" and "not teleporting" the player.
It works well with `AddForce()`, now I just have to deal with the cancellation of the previous horizontal velocity when the player changes direction so that he doesn't seem to "slide on the ice".

Comment: MovePosition does have a few advantages compared to changing the position, since it allows frame interpolation for the camera, and will send collision events, but it's not what you want.